# Vim macro broken after switching from Gnome Terminal to Byobu

Tags: 15.04, vim, byobu

In my `.vimrc` I have this line to quickly insert a `</p>` line:

```
let @l='^[I</p>^M^[^[OH^[OB'
```

I was working great in `gnome-terminal`, but in `byobu` it adds an extra line containing `H`.

How to fix that?
I would rather have my script work correctly in both `gnome-terminal` and `byobu`. Or in `byobu` only if necessary.

Comment: Also checkout [vi.se], our sister site for Vim fans!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `^[OH` and `^[OB` are intended to be home key and down arrow? In that case, why not use the `0` and `k` motions directly:

```
let @l='^[I</p>^M^[0k'
```

Or, condensing the `I` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to `O`:

```
let @l='^[O</p>^[0k'
```

(Or `^` in place of `0`, depending what you intended to do.)